# wpf ghost display or partial display of button controls on canvas

Tags: wpf, vb.net, button, canvas, telerik-radbutton

A weird display problem happens at random where a partial display or a "ghost" of buttons will appear on a canvas.

There should be a button for "6" and "7".  "Welco" should not be there

[image: There should be a button for "6" and "7". "Welco" should not be there.]

The numbered buttons are wpf buttons, the 4 on the right are telerik radbuttons.

A normal display would look like this:
[image]

99% of the time, the display is normal.  It's just at random times and with any button click that the display can mess up.  I can minimize/maximize and the display becomes normal. I capture the attached image with Snagit, then minimized the capture image.  The display was normal then.  So I don't think it's necessarily something in the xaml that's causing this.

Is there a memory issue here that's not allowing a normal display?

Thanks for any help or advice.

xaml:

```
<Canvas x:Name="canvasTop" Background="#FFFFFF" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="74" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,26,0,0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
        <StackPanel x:Name="pnlSteps" >
            <StackPanel x:Name="pnlStepProcess" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="250,10,0,10">
                <StackPanel.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray" />
                    </Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#3C2F56" />
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray" />
                        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                    </Style>
                </StackPanel.Resources>
                <Button x:Name="btnStep1" Width="22" Click="Step1Click" Height="22" Cursor="Hand" >
                    <Button.Template>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <Border CornerRadius="0" Height="21" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                <TextBlock 
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"                                           
                                    Height="20"
                                    FontSize="14">
                                    <AccessText>_1</AccessText>
                                </TextBlock>
                            </Border>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Button.Template>
                </Button>
                <Label x:Name="lineA" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="4" Width="100" />
                <Button x:Name="btnStep2" Width="22" Click="Step2Click" Height="22" Cursor="Hand" >
                    <Button.Template>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <Border CornerRadius="0" Height="21" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                <TextBlock 
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"                                           
                                    Height="20"
                                    FontSize="14">
                                    <AccessText>_2</AccessText>
                                </TextBlock>
                            </Border>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Button.Template>
                </Button>
                <Label x:Name="lineB" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="4" Width="100" />
                <Button x:Name="btnStep3" Width="22" Click="Step3Click" Height="22" Cursor="Hand" >
                    <Button.Template>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <Border CornerRadius="0" Height="21" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                <TextBlock
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"                                           
                                    Height="20"
                                    FontSize="14">
                                    <AccessText>_3</AccessText>
                                </TextBlock>
                            </Border>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Button.Template>
                </Button>
                <Label x:Name="lineC" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="4" Width="100" />
                <Button x:Name="btnStep4" Width="22" Click="Step4Click" Height="22" Cursor="Hand" >
                    <Button.Template>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <Border CornerRadius="0" Height="21" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                <TextBlock 
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"                                           
                                    Height="20"
                                    FontSize="14">
                                    <AccessText>_4</AccessText>
                                </TextBlock>
                            </Border>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Button.Template>
                </Button>
                <Label x:Name="lineD" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="4" Width="100" />
                <Button x:Name="btnStep5" Width="22" Click="Step5Click" Height="22" Cursor="Hand" >
                    <Button.Template>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <Border CornerRadius="0" Height="21" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                <TextBlock 
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"                                           
                                    Height="20"
                                    FontSize="14">
                                    <AccessText>_5</AccessText>
                                </TextBlock>
                            </Border>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Button.Template>
                </Button>
                <Label x:Name="lineE" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="4" Width="100" />
                <Button x:Name="btnStep6" Width="22" Click="Step6Click" Height="22" Cursor="Hand" >
                    <Button.Template>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <Border CornerRadius="0" Height="21" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                <TextBlock 
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"                                           
                                    Height="20"
                                    FontSize="14">
                                    <AccessText>_6</AccessText>
                                </TextBlock>
                            </Border>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Button.Template>
                </Button>
                <Label x:Name="lineF" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="4" Width="100" />
                <Button x:Name="btnStep7" Width="22" Click="Step7Click" Height="22" Cursor="Hand" >
                    <Button.Template>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <Border CornerRadius="0" Height="21" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                <TextBlock 
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"                                           
                                    Height="20"
                                    FontSize="14">
                                    <AccessText>_7</AccessText>
                                </TextBlock>
                            </Border>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Button.Template>
                </Button>
            </StackPanel>


        </StackPanel>

        <!--<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="600,0,0,0">-->
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Canvas.Right="10" >
            <telerik:RadButton x:Name="btnMessages" Click="btnMessages_Click" Background="Transparent" Height="40" Width="50" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Margin="100,0,0,0" 
                                Template="{DynamicResource RadButtonControlTemplate2}" >
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Source="" ToolTip="" Height="22" Width="50" />
                </StackPanel>
            </telerik:RadButton>
            <telerik:RadButton x:Name="btnSettings" Background="Transparent" Height="40" Width="50" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Margin="10,0,0,0" Template="{DynamicResource RadButtonControlTemplate2}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Source="" ToolTip="" Height="25" Width="50" />
                </StackPanel>

            </telerik:RadButton>
            <telerik:RadButton x:Name="btnHelp" Background="Transparent" Height="40" Width="50" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Margin="10,0,0,0" Template="{DynamicResource RadButtonControlTemplate2}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Source="" ToolTip="Help with application" Height="25" Width="50" />
                </StackPanel>
            </telerik:RadButton>
            <telerik:RadButton x:Name="btnExit" Click="btnQuit_Click" Background="Transparent" Height="40" Width="50" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Margin="10,0,0,0" Template="{DynamicResource RadButtonControlTemplate2}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Source="" ToolTip="Close application" Height="25" Width="50" />
                </StackPanel>
            </telerik:RadButton>
        </StackPanel>


        <Label x:Name="lblWelcome" Width="439" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" Height="30" 
            Foreground="#6B478E" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" Canvas.Top="40" Canvas.Right="10" />
```

Comment: Is there a reason for using a canvas rather than (say) a grid or dockpanel?

Comment: No, no reason I can think of.  That is just what was there when I took over development.  I can try Grid and see if that solves the problem.  Thanks